# Why do these three regexes split the string differenty, even though they seem equivalent?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a textarea where people can paste text. I need a regexp to split the text on empty lines. I wrote `'a\n\nb'.split('(\r?\n){2}'` and it did not give the expected result (`['a', '\n', 'b']` instead of `['a', 'b']`).

I went further and found out that these three lines all give a different result, event thoug the tree regular expressions look equivant to me, i.e. I expect all three to match two consecutive line feed characters.

```
> 'a\n\nb'.split(new RegExp('\n\n'))
< ["a", "b"]
> 'a\n\nb'.split(new RegExp('(\n){2}'))
< ["a", "
  ", "b"]
> 'a\n\nb'.split(new RegExp('(\n\n)'))
< ["a", "

  ", "b"]
```

Can someone explain why these three regexes behave different to that point ?

Comment: Because of **capturing group**, these `regex` are not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the capturing group in the second and third. From [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.split):

> If *separator* is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time *separator* is matched the results (including any **undefined** results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

You can make your capturing groups *non-capturing* groups by changing them to `(?:\n)` and `(?:\n\n)`. But note that in your second example, there's no need for a group at all, simply `\n{2}` is sufficient. (Come to that, there's no need for one in the third example either.)

---

You don't need to use a string and the `RegExp` constructor, `\n` means "newline" in a regular expression literal as well: `/\n{2}/`.

Comment: The reason I need paranthesis is because I want to match `\r\n` and `\n` with `(\r?\n)`. Thanks for the non-capturing modifier tip, it allows me to solve the problem :  `/(?:\r?\n){2}/`.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: Yes, in *that* case, you do need to group them. :-) (And happily , `\r` means carriage return in a regex, so you still don't need strings unless there's some other need for them.)